# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  trying to use jquery animate function to animate boxes but this simple code seems to jerk me off.  I am not sure what have I mistaken ? Sometimes the similar code would work perfect and sometime it seems very difficult.

```
<!doctype html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="jquery.js">
            </script>

            <style>
                #main{
                    clear:both;
                }
                #boxes{
                    position:absolute;
                    width:75%;
                }
                #box1, #box2, #box3{
                    position:relative;
                    width:200px;
                    height:200px;
                    background-color:#FFD600;
                    margin:10px;
                }
                #buttons{
                    float:right;
                }
                input{
                    display:block;
                    width:150px;
                }
            </style>

            <script>
            $('document').ready(function(){
                $("#left").bind('click', function(){
                    console.log('Left');
                    $('#box1').animate({x:"+=20px"});
                });

            });
            </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="boxes">
                    <div id="box1">

                    </div>

                    <div id="box2">

                    </div>

                    <div id="box3">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="buttons">
                        <input type="button" value="Left" id="left">
                    <input type="button" value="Right" id="right">
                    <input type="button" value="Top" id="top">
                    <input type="button" value="Bottom" id="bottom">
                    <input type="button" value="Height" id="height">
                    <input type="button" value="Width" id="width">
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/5pSca/) on JSFiddle.**

Comment: should this be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It's ok if you can move it to coderview ...

Comment: @Dmitry: I think it's more appropriate here; It is asking for help with a problem, not how to improve already-working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` isn't a CSS property. Try [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/left):

```
$('#box1').animate({left:"+=20px"});
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/5pSca/1/) on JSFiddle.**

Answer (score 2):

Try this it works perfectly :

```
$("#left").click(function(){
console.log('Left');
$('#box1').animate({left: '+=50'});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
x: "+=20px"
```

should be:

```
left: "+=20px"
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DVdby/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could not see this error in console ? JSFiddle show this. Very helpful

Comment: @insane-36: You're welcome. Yeah, you wouldn't get an error. It just fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$('#box1').animate({x:"+=20px"});
```

to this:

```
$('#box1').animate({left:"+=20px"});
```

The positions in CSS are `top` and `left`, not x and y.  Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/47vMV/.